# Export .obj in 3ds Max and render in Blender Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

Wondering if it is possible to export .obj with texture in 3ds Max and render the .obj (with all texture attached) in Blender Cycles? Or I need to do all the unwrap and texturing again in Blender?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.obj files do not contain textures, but they do preserve UVs. In other words, you will not have to re-unwrap the whole thing, but you will need a copy of any textures when importing into blender.

Comment: May I ask what is the use of .mtl file? It stores material information of .obj file?

Comment: @newtoblender Read [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541). MTL files do save some very basic material information but are very far from a reliable method of creating full blown production ready materials. Bottom line: Create your own materials using the existing textures, UVs are preserved.